# ¿ Por que al presionar el botón no me resalta la sintaxis?

Tags: html, css

#### highlightjs

Estoy usando [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) para resaltar la sintaxis, cree un botón  que al presionarlo me pinta un código en un `div`, el tema es que debería resaltarse la sintaxis pero no esta funcionando.

¿ a que se debe eso ?

```css
#pintar {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/styles/androidstudio.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="mostrar">Mostrar codigo</button>
  </div>

  <div id="pintar">
    <pre><code class="python">if True:</code></pre>
  </div>

</body>

</html>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>


<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("mostrar")
var divPintar = document.getElementById("pintar")

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    divPintar.innerHTML = ""

    divPintar.innerHTML += `
        <pre><code class='python'>if False</code></pre>`
  })
</script>
```

Comment: funciona bien antes de apretar el boton.. y se arruina cuando apretas el boton.. debe estar mal el html que le pasas al apretar el boton...

Comment: o highligth solo se esta ejecutando al cargar.. suena mas probable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te resalta la sintaxis porque **no se lo estas diciendo** al agregar el nuevo texto.

La función `initHighlightingOnLoad`, tal como en su nombre ya se intuye, inicializa los elementos afectados por `highlight.js` durante la carga inicial de la página (*OnLoad* significa *Al Cargar*). Si agregas nuevos contenidos éstos no son tomados en cuenta, porque el objeto `hljs` no parece que quede a la escucha de nada.

De hecho la función `initHighlightingOnLoad` esta obsoleta desde la versión 11.0.0 de [**highlight.js**](https://highlightjs.org/). Actualmente van por la versión **11.4.0**.

He modificado tu código para que usen esa versión y más abajo explico los cambios realizados. Aquí te dejo un snippet funcionando:

```css
#pintar {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.5.0/styles/androidstudio.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">

    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
      <div>
        <button id="mostrar">Mostrar codigo</button>
      </div>

      <div id="pintar">
        <pre><code class="python">if True:</code></pre>
      </div>

    </body>

    </html>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.4.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      hljs.highlightAll();
    </script>


    <script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("mostrar")
    var divPintar = document.getElementById("pintar")

    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        divPintar.innerHTML = ""

        divPintar.innerHTML += `
            <pre><code class='python'>if False</code></pre>`
        hljs.highlightAll()
      })
    </script>
```

**Explicación de los cambios:**

- He actualizado la versión de highlight.js a la 11.4.0 aquí:

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.4.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

- He quitado la función obsoleta `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();` y la he sustituido por la actual:

```javascript
hljs.highlightAll();
```

- Dentro de la escucha del evento `click`, he agregado la rellamada a highlighAll() para que vuelva a ejecutarse completamente en el documento actual (lo habia intentando con  `hljs.highlightElement(divPintar)` que parece más lógico, pero me cambiaba un poco el tipo de letra). Es decir:

```javascript
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        divPintar.innerHTML = ""

        divPintar.innerHTML += `
            <pre><code class='python'>if False</code></pre>`
        hljs.highlightAll()
      })
```

Prueba y ya nos dirás.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente.